# Recycler View is Not Displaying

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Issue: Recycler View is not displaying. There is no error logged. The page is just blank. I did attempt to look at other similar Recycler View issues, but I have not been able to figure out the problem. I played around with the layout to make sure views were not overlapping but that did not fix the issue. I also looked through the java file but cannot find anything wrong with it. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Personal_Wall"
    tools:openDrawer="end">




    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">



            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                elevation="4dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="#ffff"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/splashd_logo_button"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/new_splashd_logo_black"
                    android:text="hapana_button" />


            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment-containter2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">



                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/edit_icon"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="245dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
                        android:elevation="6dp"
                        android:background="@color/fui_transparent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera_icon" />



                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profile_place_holder"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
                        android:elevation="4dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/grey_oval"
                        app:civ_border_color="#fff"
                        app:civ_border_width="5dp" />

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="250dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
                        card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/temporary_banner_personal_wall"
                            android:layout_width="380dp"
                            android:layout_height="250dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/roundec_corner_rectangle_grey" />
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/personal_wall_text_first_name"
                        android:layout_width="193dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="158dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:text="First"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="30dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/personal_wall_text_last_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="210dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:text="Last"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="30dp" />


                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/small_grey_circle"
                        android:layout_width="78dp"
                        android:layout_height="52dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="408dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/small_grey_circle" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Current Location: Washington D.C."
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                        android:layout_marginTop="360dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_profile_location_on_black_24dp"

                        >

                    </TextView>


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/personal_wall_post_something_box"
                        android:layout_width="290dp"
                        android:layout_height="69dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="398dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/make_a_splash_oval" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/assists_count"
                        android:layout_width="73dp"
                        android:layout_height="38dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="550dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                        android:text="Assists"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"/>



                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/assists_count_actual_number"
                        android:layout_width="73dp"
                        android:layout_height="38dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="515dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                        android:text="3"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="22dp" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/followers_count"
                        android:layout_width="102dp"
                        android:layout_height="39dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="143dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="550dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                        android:text="Followers"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/followers_count_actual_number"
                        android:layout_width="102dp"
                        android:layout_height="39dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="144dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="515dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                        android:text="2"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="22dp" />




                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/splash_count"
                        android:layout_width="102dp"
                        android:layout_height="39dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="550dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                        android:text="Splashes"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"/>



                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/splash_count_actual_number"
                        android:layout_width="102dp"
                        android:layout_height="39dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="515dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                        android:text="5"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="22dp" />







                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="590dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />



                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="488dp"
                        android:background="#E8E8E8" />





                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/testing_scrollview"
                        android:layout_width="102dp"
                        android:layout_height="39dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="293dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1400dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                        android:text="TEST"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"/>


                </FrameLayout>


            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


        </LinearLayout>






        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_post_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="700dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/fragment_container_3">
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>








        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container_3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
            <!-- Main content -->
            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
                app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_selected_color"
                app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_selected_color"
                app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
                app:itemIconSize="@dimen/bottom_navigation_icon_size"
                />
        </FrameLayout>



    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>








    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout> 


---------------------------------------------------------




package com.example.updatedhapana1;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;


import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

import static com.example.updatedhapana1.Personal_Wall_Edit.Gallery_Pick2;


public class Personal_Wall extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    Window window;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Uri uri;

    private RecyclerView postList; //TRYING RECYCLER VIEW AGAIN AHHHHHHHHHH!


    private String currentUserID;
    private DatabaseReference UsersReference;
    private CircleImageView profile_image;
    private StorageReference UserProfileImageRef;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ImageView post_question;
    private ImageButton edit_profile;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private ImageView banner_view;
    private ImageButton splash_gallery;


    FirebaseUser currentUser;

    TextView mfirstname;
    TextView mlastname;
    TextView firstname_for_main_profile;
    TextView lastname_for_main_profile;

    NavigationView mNavigationView;
    CircleImageView m_nav_header_profile_image;
    CircleImageView profile_placeholder_personal_wall;
    CircleImageView little_circle_personal_wall;

    FirebaseDatabase mfirebaseDatabase;
    final static int Gallery_Pick = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_personal__wall);
        little_circle_personal_wall = findViewById(R.id.small_grey_circle); //this is to bring in the profile picture from the database


        //////This change the status bar color and the status bar text color. I wanted the status bar to be white.//////////
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 21) {
            window = this.getWindow();
            window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);//  set status text dark


        }
        //////This change the status bar color and the status bar text color. I wanted the status bar to be white.//////////


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        UsersReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID);
        UserProfileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");
        profile_image = findViewById(R.id.profile_place_holder_edit);
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        profile_placeholder_personal_wall = findViewById(R.id.profile_place_holder);
        banner_view = findViewById(R.id.temporary_banner_personal_wall);


        //RECYCLERVIEW//
        postList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_post_list);
        postList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        postList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        //RECYCLERVIEW//

----------------------------------------------------

@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Posts> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Posts>()
                .setQuery(UsersReference, Posts.class)
                .build();



        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts,FindPostsViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, FindPostsViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FindPostsViewHolder findPostsViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Posts posts)
                    {
                        findPostsViewHolder.first_name.setText(posts.getFirst_name());
                        findPostsViewHolder.last_name.setText(posts.getLast_name());
                        findPostsViewHolder.post_date.setText(posts.getPost_date());
                        findPostsViewHolder.post_body_text.setText(posts.getPost_body_text());



                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public FindPostsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_layout_2, viewGroup, false);
                        FindPostsViewHolder viewHolder = new FindPostsViewHolder(view);
                        return viewHolder;
                    }
                };

        postList.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.startListening();







    }

    public static class FindPostsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        TextView first_name, last_name, post_body_text, post_date;


        public FindPostsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            first_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_first_name);
            last_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_last_name);
            post_date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_date_and_time);
            post_body_text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.the_post);


        }
    }


----------------------------------------------

package com.example.updatedhapana1;

public class Posts
{

    public String first_name, last_name, post_body_text, post_date;


    //this is an empty contstructor- this is required//
    public Posts ()
    {

    }
    //this is an empty contstructor- this is required//



    public Posts(String first_name, String last_name, String post_body_text, String post_date) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.post_body_text = post_body_text;
        this.post_date = post_date;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getPost_body_text() {
        return post_body_text;
    }

    public void setPost_body_text(String post_body_text) {
        this.post_body_text = post_body_text;
    }

    public String getPost_date() {
        return post_date;
    }

    public void setPost_date(String post_date) {
        this.post_date = post_date;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **700** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested your code, but this is what I suspect. From your XML it seems like you have linear layout and recycler view in 2 separate components and your LinearLayout is match_parent.
So I am assuming it's taking the entire space.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your last FrameLayout where is height is match_parent and is overlapping everything.
If it's not this layout try to replace others layout by wrap_content or when your run your app, you have "layout inspector" in Android Studio and you can find your error.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove this from your Recyclerview**: `android:layout_marginTop="700dp""`.
It has set the top margin **700dp** which makes it go out of the screen.

Comment: thank you for your help. unfortunately, the recycler view is still not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
I figured out my issue. My recycler view items were not displaying because of how my data was structured in firebase. Thank you everyone for your help.